# Elasticsearch suggestion is merging result of two types

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have 2 Types in one index and both have Suggest field (as required )

```
public class LegalAreaSearchModel : LegalAreaModel
{
    public SuggestField Suggest
    {
        get
        {
            List<string> input = new List<string>();
            string[] childArea = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.LegalArea) ? this.LegalArea.Split(' ') : new string[] { "" };
            string[] ParentArea = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Parent) ? this.Parent.Split(' ') : new string[] { "" };
            input.AddRange(childArea);
            input.AddRange(ParentArea);
            return

                new SuggestField
                {
                    Input = input,
                    Output = this.LegalArea,
                    Payload = new
                    {
                        Id = this.RowId,
                        Name = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Parent) ? this.Parent + "/" + this.LegalArea : this.LegalArea,
                        Type = "Specialization"
                    },
                    Weight = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.LegalArea) ? this.LegalArea.Length : 0
                };

        }
    }
}
```

AND

```
public class LegalDocumentSearchModel : LegalDocumentModel
{


    public LegalDocumentSearchModel()
    {
        //this = ObjectCopier.Clone<LegalDocumentSearchModel>(legalDocumentSearchModel);
        SupplierDetails = new List<LegalDocumentSupplierDetailForSearch>();
        CategoryDetails = new List<CategoryDetails>();

    }

    [Nested()]
    public List<LegalDocumentSupplierDetailForSearch> SupplierDetails { get; set; }

    [Nested()]
    public List<CategoryDetails> CategoryDetails { get; set; }

    public SuggestField Suggest
    {
        get
        {
            return
                    new SuggestField
                    {
                        Input = new List<string>(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Name) ? this.Name.Split(' ') : new string[] { "" }) { this.Name },
                        Output = this.Name,
                        Payload = new
                        {
                            Id = this.RowId,
                            SEOFriendlyURLName = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.SEOFriendlyURLName) ? string.Concat(this.SEOFriendlyURLName) : string.Empty,
                            Name = this.Name,
                            ProductType = this.ProductType,
                            Description = this.Description

                        },
                        Weight = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Description) ? this.Description.Length : 0
                    };
        }
    }

}
public class LegalDocumentSupplierDetailForSearch
{
    public string PinCode { get; set; }
    public string Lattitude { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }

}
public class CategoryDetails
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

now my search is as follows

```
List<AdvocateListingSuggestionModel> lsResult = new List<AdvocateListingSuggestionModel>();
        var result = _searchProvider.Client.Suggest<LegalAreaSearchModel>(s => s
                                                .Index(SearchConfigurationManager.DefaultSearchIndex)
                                                .Completion("ml-la-suggestions", c => c
                                                .Text(Search)
                                                .Field(p => p.Suggest)
                                                .Fuzzy(fz => fz
                                                    .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.Auto))
                                                )
            );
```

I am getting result from other type as well(mix) of both how can we restrict result from only one type

Type1.LegalAreaSearchModel
Type 2.LegalDocumentSearchModel

my index creation is as follows

```
  public static bool CheckForIndex(ElasticSearchProvider searchProvider)
    {

        Nest.IndexExistsRequest idr = new Nest.IndexExistsRequest(Nest.Indices.Index(new Nest.IndexName() { Name = SearchConfigurationManager.DefaultSearchIndex }));
        var indxres = searchProvider.Client.IndexExists(idr);

        if (!indxres.Exists)
        {
            searchProvider.Client.CreateIndex(SearchConfigurationManager.DefaultSearchIndex, i => i
            .Settings(s => s
                .NumberOfShards(2)
                .NumberOfReplicas(0)
                .Analysis(analysis => analysis
                    .Tokenizers(tokenizers => tokenizers
                        .Pattern("ml-id-tokenizer", p => p.Pattern(@"\W+"))
                    )
                    .TokenFilters(tokenfilters => tokenfilters
                        .WordDelimiter("ml-id-words", wd => wd
                            .SplitOnCaseChange()
                            .PreserveOriginal()
                            .SplitOnNumerics()
                            .GenerateNumberParts(false)
                            .GenerateWordParts()
                        )
                    )
                    .Analyzers(analyzers => analyzers
                        .Custom("ml-id-analyzer", c => c
                            .Tokenizer("ml-id-tokenizer")
                            .Filters("ml-id-words", "lowercase")
                        )
                        .Custom("ml-id-keyword", c => c
                            .Tokenizer("keyword")
                            .Filters("lowercase")
                        )
                    )
                )
            ));
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Creatining Document Type as follows

```
 public bool CreateDocumentIndex()
    {
        bool retVal = false;
        if (Common.CheckForIndex(_searchProvider))
        {
            var res = _searchProvider.Client.Map<LegalDocumentSearchModel>(m =>
                                                                   m.Index(SearchConfigurationManager.DefaultSearchIndex)
                                                                   .Type(this.type)
                                                                   .AutoMap()
                                                                   .Properties(ps => ps
                                                                   .String(s => s
                                                                          .Name(p => p.Id)
                                                                          .Analyzer("ml-id-analyzer")
                                                                              .Fields(f => f
                                                                                  .String(p => p.Name("keyword").Analyzer("ml-id-keyword"))
                                                                                  .String(p => p.Name("raw").Index(FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed))
                                                                              )
                                                                      )
                                                                   .Completion(c => c
                                                                          .Name(p => p.Suggest)
                                                                          .Payloads()
                                                                      )
                                                                   ));

            retVal = res.IsValid;


        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

creating LegalArea Type as follows

```
 public bool CreateLegalAreaIndex()
    {
        bool retVal = false;
        if (Common.CheckForIndex(_searchProvider))
        {
            var res = _searchProvider.Client.Map<LegalAreaSearchModel>(m =>
                                                                    m.Index(SearchConfigurationManager.DefaultSearchIndex)
                                                                    .Type(this.type)
                                                                    .AutoMap()
                                                                    .Properties(ps => ps
                                                                    .String(s => s
                                                                           .Name(p => p.Id)
                                                                           .Analyzer("ml-id-analyzer")
                                                                               .Fields(f => f
                                                                                   .String(p => p.Name("keyword").Analyzer("ml-id-keyword"))
                                                                                   .String(p => p.Name("raw").Index(FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed))
                                                                               )
                                                                       )
                                                                    .Completion(c => c
                                                                           .Name(p => p.Suggest)
                                                                           .Payloads()
                                                                       )
                                                                    ));

            retVal = res.IsValid;
        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

now when i am running legal area suggestions as follows

```
 public List<AdvocateListingSuggestionModel> LegalAreaSuggestion(string Search)
    {
        List<AdvocateListingSuggestionModel> lsResult = new List<AdvocateListingSuggestionModel>();
        var result = _searchProvider.Client.Suggest<LegalAreaSearchModel>(s => s
                                                .Index(SearchConfigurationManager.DefaultSearchIndex)
                                                .Completion("ml-la-suggestions", c => c
                                                .Text(Search)
                                                .Field(p => p.Suggest)
                                                .Fuzzy(fz => fz
                                                    .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.Auto))
                                                )
            );
        if (result.IsValid)
        {
            lsResult = result.Suggestions["ml-la-suggestions"]
                    .FirstOrDefault()
                    .Options
                    .Select(suggest => suggest.Payload<AdvocateListingSuggestionModel>()).ToList();
        }
        return lsResult;
    }
```

I am getting results of LegalDocumentSearchModel as well.pls advise

Thanks

Comment: what version of NEST are you using and what version of Elasticsearch are you running against?

Comment: Nest 2.1.0 and Elasticsearch 2.3

Comment: @RussCam any solutions?

Comment: what is the other type? You show the `Suggest` property accessor but not the type declaration. Can you show this and also show what the mappings look like in the index?

Comment: updated question with all details pls have a look

Comment: @RussCam added details in question.

Comment: what is the value of `this.type` in each of the mappings?

Comment: @RussCam this.type is a string value in CreateLegalAreaIndex this.type="legalarea" and in CreateDocumentIndex this.type="documents" bu adding this i can access index by this name

Comment: @RussCam updated comments

Comment: @RussCam help needed

Comment: @RussCam any other details you want for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggesters work at the index level, that is, [one Finite State Transducer (FST) is created for a field ***per index***](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_index_time_search_as_you_type.html) so if you have two types with the same field name in the same index (both fields **must** be of the same type), both types will have data represented in the one FST.

We can see this with a simple example. Here we have two types with completion fields that we're going to index into the same index

```
public class Band
{
    public int Id { get; set;}

    public  CompletionField<object> Suggest { get; set;}
}

public class Sport
{
    public int Id { get; set;}

    public CompletionField<object> Suggest { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var defaultIndex = "default-index";
    var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
            .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);

    var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

    // just so we can re-run this example...
    if (client.IndexExists(defaultIndex).Exists)
        client.DeleteIndex(defaultIndex);

    client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex, ci => ci
        .Mappings(m => m
            .Map<Band>(l => l
                .AutoMap()
                .Properties(p => p
                    .Completion(c => c
                        .Name(n => n.Suggest)
                    )
                )
            )
            .Map<Sport>(l => l
                .AutoMap()
                .Properties(p => p
                    .Completion(c => c
                        .Name(n => n.Suggest)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    var bands = new List<Band>
    {
        new Band { Id = 1, Suggest = new CompletionField<object> { Input = new [] {"Bowling for Soup"} } },
        new Band { Id = 2, Suggest = new CompletionField<object> { Input = new [] {"Fastball"} } },
        new Band { Id = 3, Suggest = new CompletionField<object> { Input = new [] {"Dropkick Murphys"} } },
        new Band { Id = 4, Suggest = new CompletionField<object> { Input = new [] {"Yellowcard"} } },
        new Band { Id = 5, Suggest = new CompletionField<object> { Input = new [] {"American Football"} } },
    };

    client.IndexMany(bands);

    var sports = new List<Sport>
    {
        new Sport { Id = 1, Suggest = new CompletionField<object> { Input = new [] {"Bowling"} } },
        new Sport { Id = 2, Suggest = new CompletionField<object> { Input = new [] {"Football"} } },
        new Sport { Id = 3, Suggest = new CompletionField<object> { Input = new [] {"Baseball"} } },
        new Sport { Id = 4, Suggest = new CompletionField<object> { Input = new [] {"Table Tennis"} } },
        new Sport { Id = 5, Suggest = new CompletionField<object> { Input = new [] {"American Football"} } },
    };

    client.IndexMany(sports);
    client.Refresh(defaultIndex);

    var suggestResponse = client.Suggest<Band>(s => s
        .Completion("suggestion", cs => cs
            .Text("Bo")
            .Field(f => f.Suggest)
        )
    );
}
```

We get back the following from our suggest call

```
{
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "suggestion" : [ {
    "text" : "Bo",
    "offset" : 0,
    "length" : 2,
    "options" : [ {
      "text" : "Bowling",
      "score" : 1.0
    }, {
      "text" : "Bowling for Soup",
      "score" : 1.0
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

We get a suggestion of both a `Band` type and a `Sport` type in the results. Perhaps not what we expected or wanted, but that's how suggesters work. Note that in the `.Suggest<T>()` call, the type `T` is  used to provide strongly typed access to properties that may be used in the query. In this example, the `.Suggest` field of type `Band`.

The recommended solution here is to have separate indices for different types; you can still query across multiple indices when you need to and avoid the pitfalls that can come with having multiple types in the same index.

With that aside, you can get this to work by using a [Context Suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/suggester-context.html) and taking advantage of [category context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/suggester-context.html#_indexing_category_contexts) for the completion type mapping. Ideally, you want to use a field that exists within the document for the category to afford you flexibility in the category, but you can however use a metadata field if you want to. I recommend investigating and researching approaches for your domain.

With our previous example, if we now include category context in the mapping (*same code as before but with this updated mapping*)

```
client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex, ci => ci
    .Mappings(m => m
        .Map<Band>(l => l
            .AutoMap()
            .Properties(p => p
                .Completion(c => c
                    .Name(n => n.Suggest)
                    .Context(sc => sc
                        .Category("type", csc => csc
                            // recommend that you use another field on
                            // the document here instead of a metadata field
                            .Field("_type")
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        .Map<Sport>(l => l
            .AutoMap()
            .Properties(p => p
                .Completion(c => c
                    .Name(n => n.Suggest)
                    .Context(sc => sc
                        .Category("type", csc => csc
                            // recommend that you use another field on
                            // the document here instead of a metadata field
                            .Field("_type")
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

And use category context whilst searching

```
var suggestResponse = client.Suggest<Band>(s => s
    .Completion("suggestion", cs => cs
        .Text("Bo")
        .Field(f => f.Suggest)
        .Context(d => d.Add("type", "band"))
    )
);
```

then we get the desired result

```
{
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "suggestion" : [ {
    "text" : "Bo",
    "offset" : 0,
    "length" : 2,
    "options" : [ {
      "text" : "Bowling for Soup",
      "score" : 1.0
    } ]
  } ]
}
```